# Сделать текст ссылкой только на определенном разрешении

Tags: css3, адаптивная-верстка, ссылки, меню, media-queries

На сайте боковое меню выполнено в виде аккордеона (html/css). При нажатии на заголовок, раскрывается блок с описанием раздела. Именно это краткое описание является ссылкой на страницу.

НО при малых разрешениях экрана (@media screen...), div с меню смещается вниз (над футером) и в этом положении не раскрывается при нажатии.

Проблема обнаружилась в том, что ссылка в таком случае становится недоступной.
Нужно каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы на малых экранах ссылкой становился заголовок меню(панель аккордеона).

Возможно ли это? Я JS не владею, к сожалению. HTML/CSS с трудом освоила. Остальное могу сделать только по аналогии с каким-то примером (например, свои url подставить в коде или поменять текст/разрешение).

Что-то смутно думается про псевдоклассы. Это поможет? 
Как можно решить мою задачу?
Спасибо.

```html
<div class="accordion">
        <ul>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Комнаты в СПб</h3>
        <div class="msg">
        <p><a href="komnat.html" class="ndec">Это раздел для тех, кто хочет      снять комнату, а не квартиру</a></p></div>
</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Средние цены</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p><a href="price.html" class="ndec">Средние цены на квартиры и комнаты внаем по районам города</a></p></div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Договор (образец)</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p><a href="dogovor.html" class="ndec">Скачать бланк договора или читать онлайн</a></p>
</div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">О компании</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p><a href="rabota.html" class="ndec">Наши услуги. Подробнее о         компании и условиях работы для контрагентов. Приглашаем к сотрудничеству</a></p>
</div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Доска объявлений</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p>В обозримой переспективе на сайте появится  доска объявлений</p></div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Каталог сайтов</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p><a href="katalog.html" class="ndec">Каталог полезных ресурсов посвященных недвижимости и не только</a></p></div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Карта сайта</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p><a href="navig.html" class="ndec">Для удобства навигации и более структурированного представления обо всей информации, представленной на этот ресурсе, можно воспользоваться картой сайта                            </a></p></div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Карта СПб</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p><a href="kartaspb.html" class="ndec">Карта Петербурга</a></p></div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Схема метро Петербурга</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p><a href="metro.html" class="ndec">Карта метро СПб. Режим работы станций</a></p></div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Фото СПб</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p><img src="adapt_img/sankt-petersburg-706422_960_720.jpg" width="1024" height="768" alt=""/>Здесь мы разместим фотографии города. Ожидаемая дата заполнения раздела - 15 марта2017</p>
</div>
</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Достопримечательности  СПб</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p>В данном разделе появится список наиболее популярных достопримечательностей СПб и просто интересных мест города. Напишите нам, какие объекты культуры или какие исторические места Вам интересны.</p>
</div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Петербург музеи</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p>Этот раздел сайта будет посвящен замечательным музеям нашего города. Мы планируем размещать здесь анонсы выставок и мероприятий самых известных музеев СПб для туристов, приезжающих в Санкт-Петербург на несколько дней.</p>
</div>
</li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <i></i>
        <h3 class="title_block">Мосты Петербурга</h3>
        <div class="msg"><p>Развод мостов. График. Фотографии</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

А в стилях указано:

```
    /* Формируем базовый контейнер аккордеона */
    .accordion {
    width: 100%;

    /*ширина произвольная выбирается
    *в зависимости от места размещения */
    max-width: 600px;
    min-height: 0;
    display: block;

    /* относительное позиционирование */
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #E4EBED;
    overflow: hidden}

    /* заголовки панелей аккордеона */
    .accordion h3 {
    font-size: 2.2vmin;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000000;
    background: #E4EBED;
    border-top: 1px solid #C9D1C7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C9D1C7;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;}

    /* заголовки панелей аккордеона при наведении
    * в данном варианте не срабатывает*/

    /* .accordion h2:hover {
    display: block;
    background-color: #005049;}
```

*/

```
    /* Формируем блоки с содержанием */
    .msg {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 800px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0);}

    /* оформляем параграфы */
    .msg p {
    color: rgba(48, 69, 92, 0.8);
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 0 20px;}

    /* Позаботимся о небольших экранах */
    @media (max-width: 550px) {
    .accordion {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;}
    } 

    /* Формируем неупорядоченный список */
    .accordion ul {
    list-style: none;
    perspective: 900;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;}

    /* Определяем и формируем отдельный элемент списка 
    * в который поместим скрытый флажок,
    * заголовок панелей и блок с содержанием*/
    .accordion ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;}

    /* устанавливаем время ожидания перед воспроизведением анимации 
    * на основе нумерации в дереве элементов*/
    .accordion ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;}

    .accordion ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.75s;}
    .accordion ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 1s;}

    .accordion ul li:last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 0;}

    /* Сформируем  указатель переключения состояния аккордеона */
    .accordion ul li i {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-6px, 0);
    margin-top: 16px;

    /* расположим указатель на панели заголовка справа */
    right: 25px;}

    /* "Рисуем " сам указатель */
    .accordion ul li i:before, .accordion ul li i:after {content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 3px;
    height: 9px;}

    /* Добавляем элемент трансформации указателя при переключении */
    .accordion ul li i:before {
    transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);}

    .accordion ul li i:after {
    transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);}

    /* Делаем чекбокс скрытым*/
    .accordion ul li input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 3px;}

    /* Когда у флажка установлен checked  
    * блок с содержанием скрыт*/
    .accordion ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.msg {
    margin-top: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 50%);}

    /* А указатель показывает вниз */
    .accordion ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:before {
    transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(45deg);}

    .accordion ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:after {
    transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);}

    /*  Устанавливаем эффект перехода 
    * между двумя состояниями указателя */
    div.msg, ul li i:before, ul li i:after {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}
    /**
    * Изображения внутри аккордеона
    * ...сделаем их отзывчивыми */
    .accordion .msg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);}

    /* полноразмерная картинка */
    .msg img .large-img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;}
    /* миниатюра слева */
    .msg img.img-left {
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 15px 5px 0;}
    /* миниатюра справа */
    .msg img.img-right {
    width: 25%;
    float:right;
    margin:5px 0 5px 15px;}

    /* Встраиваемое видео */
    .video-responsive {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);}

    /* Предусмотрим использование кода встраиваемого видео
    *через iframe, object или embed */
    .video-responsive iframe,
    .video-responsive object,
    .video-responsive embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;}
```

Comment: оформите пожалуйста вопрос со вставкой кода с помощью кнопки "вставить код". А то это слишком нечитаемо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте скрытый елемент со ссылкой и в media запросе при нужном разрешении, скройте текст, а скрытую ссылку отбразите. В вашем случае нужно добавить в @media (max-width: 550px) {} блок, как я понял.